# Can I reduce heavy whipping cream for a sauce a day ahead of use?

Tags: cream

Can this be done the day before using it for a sauce?  Because of a time crunch, I was wondering if I could reduce the heavy whipping cream the day before I make the actual sauce?

Answer (score 2):

The only issue with reducing cream and then cooling it, is when you then reheat it you'll likely find the sauce will split leaving a layer of fat floating on the top. This is easily fixed by adding a touch more cream during the reheating process.
It's how we deal with white wine cream sauce at work.